# Laravel: multiple where clauses in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationships

I am not able to create this sql query on laravel:

```
select * from `events_theatre` where
    event_id IN (
        select id from events where (`events`.`id` = `events_theatre`.`event_id` and `user_id` = 1 and `event_type` ='theatre') and `events`.`deleted_at` is null
    )
    or event_id IN (
        select id from events inner join events_managers on events.id = events_managers.event_id and events_managers.user_id = 1
    )
    and `events_theatre`.`deleted_at` is null
```

The Events_Theatre model has this relationship:

```
public function event()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\MyEvent', 'id');
}
```

While the MyEvent model has this relationship:

```
public function managers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'events_managers', 'event_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Pratically an Events_Theatre model is an Event model, and an Event model may have many managers but just 1 admin.

I need to get that Events_Theatre (and their MyEvent) whose user is an admin or one of the managers.

I tried with this eloquent query:

```
$list = App\Events_Theatre::whereIn('event_id', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->where(['user_id' => Auth::id(), 'event_type' => 'theatre'])
        ->orWhereHas('managers', function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        });
});
```

But I get this sql query:

```
select * from `events_theatre` where
exists (
    select * from `events` where (
        `events`.`id` = `events_theatre`.`event_id` and `user_id` = 1 and `event_type` = 'theatre'
    ) or exists (
        select * from `users` inner join `events_managers` on `users`.`id` = `events_managers`.`user_id` where `events_managers`.`event_id` = `events`.`id` and `user_id` = 1
    )
    and `events`.`deleted_at` is null
) and `events_theatre`.`deleted_at` is null
```

But its wrong. How can I solve this?

Thanks

**UPDATED**

I got the answer. This is the eloquent code I used:

```
$list = Events_Theatre::whereHas('event', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->where(['user_id' => Auth::id(), 'event_type' => 'theatre']);
})->orWhereHas('event', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->whereHas('managers', function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        });
})->get();
```

Comment: In where table is your fields user_id and event_type, of the first select into exist?

Comment: Can you please state plainly what conditions you are trying to search for. It's a bit confusing inferring from all the different sql you've pasted.

Comment: I need to get that Events_Theatre (and their MyEvent) whose user is an admin or one of the managers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [has](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) method

```
App\Events_Theatre::has('event')->orhas('managers')->get();
```